# Why is it necessary to specify the type in this C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this minimal, contrived example of C++ code, with a template struct with a default type parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T=int>
struct AddsFourtyTwo {
    template <class U>
    static U do_it(U u) {
        return u + static_cast<T>(42);
    }
};

int main() {
    double d = 1.24;
    std::cout << AddsFourtyTwo::do_it(d) << std::endl;
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error with g++ 4.9.1:

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:14:18: error: 'template<class T> struct AddsFourtyTwo' used without template parameters
     std::cout << AddsFourtyTwo::do_it(d) << std::endl;
                  ^
```

If I specify int for T, then it compiles and produces the expected output (43.24). My question is, why is this necessary to do? What does the default type parameter do in the definition of AddsFourtyTwo, if you need to specify the type anyway?

Comment: The class is still a template, so you need to give it an empty pair of brackets.

Comment: You don't have to specify the type, but you do need angle brackets. `AddsFourtyTwo<>` is OK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to specify the type, but the language disallows using a template as an actual type without specifying *some* argument list:

```
std::cout << AddsFourtyTwo<>::do_it(d) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the template class requires the following syntax:

```
std::cout << AddsFourtyTwo<>::do_it(d) << std::endl;
```

will compile and use the default parameter. That's confusing since the same is not required for templated methods.